# Посчитать количество знаков препинания в строке

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы

По условию задачи нужно ввести строку и посчитать в ней количество знаков препинания.
Код который получился у меня:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        char s[50];
        const char *mas[] = {".", ",", "!", "?", ";", ":", "-"};
        cout << "Ввод строки не более 50 символов" << endl;
        gets(s);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(mas); k++) {
                if(s[i] == mas[k]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\nВ строке было " << count << "знаков препинания.";
        return 0;
    }
```

На `s[i] == mas[k]` компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')

Но разве `s[i]` это не char, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет `const char *mas[]` это массив **указателей** на `char` или проще говоря - массив строк. И инициализируете вы его строками (символами в двойных кавычках).

Должно быть так

```
const char mas[] = {'.', ',', '!', '?', ';', ':', '-'};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `const char *mas = { ".!?;:-" };` - вместо твоей записи
2. `cin >> s` - ты же `iostream` подключил, пользуйся
3. `sizeof()` - возвращает не размер массива, заведи `const int N = 6` и все

Answer (score 1):

Я немного переделал

```
 const int sz = 50;
    char s[sz + 1];
           char mas[] = {'.', ',', '!', '?', ';', ':', '-'};           
           cin.getline(s, sz + 1); // введет не более sz символов плюс '\0'
           cout << s << endl;
           int count = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
               for(size_t k = 0; k < sizeof(mas); ++k) {
                   if(s[i] == mas[k]) {
                       ++count;
                   }
               }
           }           
           cout  << count ;
```